# Excel checkboxes (VBA): Return a value if multiple boxes are checked

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

When "Yes" is checked for "per project limits" only, form A applies. When it is checked off for "per location limits," Form B applies. But if I am checking both, form C applies.

I included the spreadsheet and formula I use for each checkbox. check9 is for per project limits, while check10 is for per location limits.

[Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMtpx.jpg)

```
  Private Sub check9_Click()
  If check9.Value = True Then
  Range("G24").Value = "Form A"
Else
  Range("G24").Value = " "

End If
End Sub

  Private Sub check10_Click()
  If check10.Value = True Then
  Range("G26").Value = "Form B"

Else
  Range("G26").Value = " "
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the status of the other checkbox when deciding the form. Something like this:

```
Private Sub check9_Click()
    If check9.Value = True and check10.value = True Then
        Range("G24").Value = "Form C"
    ElseIf check9.Value = True and check10.Value = False Then
        Range("G24").Value = "Form B"
    ElseIf check9.Value = False and check10.Value = True Then
        Range("G24").Value = "Form A"
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub check10_Click()
    If check9.Value = True and check10.value = True Then
        Range("G24").Value = "Form C"
    ElseIf check9.Value = True and check10.Value = False Then
        Range("G24").Value = "Form B"
    ElseIf check9.Value = False and check10.Value = True Then
        Range("G24").Value = "Form A"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello,

I want forms A, C, and B to appear in cells G24, G25, and G26, respectively. I adjusted the code so that it would be empty if none are checked. But if I try to click both, Form C and Form A or Form B would show, depending on which I checked "yes" to at first. 

Any suggestions?

Comment: So checking box1 clears G25 and G26 `IF` box2 is unchecked. `IF` box2 is checked and box1 is not checked, `THEN` clear G24 and G26. Etc. You have 2 events (checknn_click events) and two properties to evaluate (checknn.value). Simply `check the status of the other checkbox` in the click event to determine the values of G24, 25, and 26.

Answer (score 0):

call this function off each click

```
public function FormNeeded()    
    if check9.value=true and check10.value=false then
         range("g26").value="Form1"
    elseif check9.value=false and check10.value=true then
         range("g26").value="Form2"
    elseif check9.value=true and check10.value=true then
         range("g26").value="Form3"
    end if
end function
```